# Twitter bootstrap responsive utility

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using twitter-bootstrap for a website i've built and i'm handling a problem once i'm trying to display data that should be visible only for smartphone users ;

using `<div class="visible-phone">This is a test div</div>` does not show any data at all on smartphones ,
while `<div class="visible-desktop">This is a test div</div>` works just fine for computers.

How could I handle this problem?

Thanks in advnace

Comment: Have you tried it in portrait or landscape mode ? Because landscape mode might have more than 767px in width, which means it should display the visible-tablet or visible-desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this issue @ [here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2564)

Modifying your css to look like this is a good solution to this issue

> // Visibility utilities
>
> // For desktops .visible-phone     { display: none; } .visible-tablet 
>   { display: none; } .visible-desktop   {  } .hidden-phone      {  }
>   .hidden-tablet     {  } .hidden-desktop    { display: none; }
>
> // Phones only @media (max-width: 767px) {   // Show   .visible-phone 
>   {  }   // Hide   .hidden-phone      { display: none !important; }   //
>   Hide everything else   .hidden-desktop    {  }   .visible-desktop   {
>   display: none !important; } }
>
> // Tablets & small desktops only @media (min-width: 768px) and
>   (max-width: 979px) {   // Show   .visible-tablet    {  }   // Hide
>   .hidden-tablet     { display: none !important; }   // Hide everything
>   else   .hidden-desktop    {  }   .visible-desktop   { display: none
>   !important; } }

I hope this solves your issue